# Application Freeze in loop when using Sleep

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.5

I have an application that I made to connect to a device using telnet, the application freeze/crash when I started it .. I have `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);` in couple locations of the application. I was wondering, is there a way to have the application active and buttons are useable but the some operations are only impacted by the sleep operation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you have the `Sleep(3000)` in the first place?

Comment: You could google Dispatcher, Task and async/await.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `Thread.Sleep`, especially on the UI thread.  This will cause a hang - by design.

Since you're using .NET 4.5, you can use `await Task.Delay(3000);` to asynchronously "sleep", which won't block the UI.  However, this is typically a sign of a poor design - "waiting" is something that really shouldn't need to happen in a UI application in general.  There are typically better approaches, such as using `await` on the asynchronous operation for which you're waiting, etc.

Comment: Thank you @Reed Copsey. But, do you have any codes available for Threads? I'm currently stuck and need assistance

Comment: @sikas You'd have to give us a lot more information about what you're doing.  My blog has a whole series on threading, though (reedcopsey.com)

Answer (score 1):

This requires a bit of an explanation. There are some threads that are special in this case the ui thread where the rendering of your Ui happens and the events from the input devices are handled. If this thread spends time doing any calculations windows will state that your application has frozen. Since you are using Thread.Sleep on it you get this result.

**Articles to understand the problem**

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870(v=vs.110).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd744765(v=vs.85).aspx

**Recommended Solutions**

On the Button press dispatch a thread that goes and does the work that you need to happen. On the meantime change the cursor for the mouse to indicate that work is happening or show a progress bar. Once it finishes you can fire(dispatchet) an event that changes the ui.

I would do something similar to:

```
// The Work to perform on another thread 
ThreadStart start = delegate() { // ... // This will work as its using the dispatcher 
DispatcherOperation op = Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( DispatcherPriority.Normal, new  Action<string>(SetStatus),
"From Other Thread (Async)");
DispatcherOperationStatus status = op.Status; while (status !=   DispatcherOperationStatus.Completed) { status = op.Wait(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));  
if (status == DispatcherOperationStatus.Aborted)
{ // Alert Someone } } }; // Create the thread and kick it started! new  
Thread(start).Start();
```

More Examples at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx

Comment: Let me explain more. What I do is, the user clicks on "Start" Button, and the application logs in a device an gets the specific logs. After that, it perform the same again and again, till the user clicks stop. Is this applicable by your code?

Comment: You can make a loop and keep updating inside the thread you started. on the last link the background worker would be a good example.

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling sleep within your application it will do just that. If you do not want your application to hang, you will need to create a new thread that does whatever monitoring and waiting you want it to do, if a particular condition you are looking for is met, then use a callback to your parent thread to perform whatever task you want to do.